# Rails i18n API Triple Dashes/Hyphens, Ellipsises and Newlines

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, internationalization, rails-i18n

I am using i18n API for a purpose. I seed a MySQL database with:

```
Translation.find_or_create_by(locale: 'en', key:'key1', value: 'value1')
```

However, after seed, the data is saved on database as:

```
locale: en
key: key1
value: --- value1\n...\n
```

All columns are varchar(255) and 'utf8_unicode_ci'.

On Rails i18n documentation, I could not find an explanation for this.

Because of that problem, I can not use find_or_create_by() method. It do/can not check the value column and adds duplicate entries.

Is there any solution for that?

Translate model:

```
Translation = I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation

if Translation.table_exists?
  I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.new

  I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Memoize)
  I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Memoize)
  I18n::Backend::Simple.send(:include, I18n::Backend::Pluralization)

  I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(I18n::Backend::Simple.new, I18n.backend)
end
```

Comment: Can add the source of the Translation model? (looks like the setter for the value attribute is being overridden)

Comment: I added it to the original question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're seing in your `value` column is the value [serialized to YAML](https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n-active_record/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/active_record/translation.rb#L54) (that's done by the `I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord::Translation`); which is required, among other things, for pluralization.

`#find_or_create_by` doesn't work nicely when the value stored in the database needs serialization

To do a simple seed try:

```
Translation.create_with(value: 'value1').find_or_create_by(locale: 'en', key: 'key1')
```

Comment: I have changed my code as:

Translation.find_or_create_by(locale: 'en', key:'key1').update_attributes(:value => 'value1')

and it has also worked.

Despite I got the solution, I was wondering the purpose of these values, now I got it also.